# when using duckling, Getting wrong start date with "from the 22 to the 30th of July"

Tags: facebook, date, duckling

With "from the 22 to the 30th of July", the start date is not well recognized. It responds 2018-06-29 and not the right value 2018-07-22.

any fix?

Comment: please put some effort into stackover questions. add the relevant code and a much more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let me know how you are using duckling?
I am able to get proper interval by both methods:

1. Directly pasting the text on website: https://duckling.wit.ai/
2. Running the duckling-example-exe server and hitting it with the the following curl request:

curl -XPOST http://0.0.0.0:8000/parse --data 'locale=en_US&text=from the 22 to the 30th of July'

For method 2, see the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/duckling)